# Creating Form with checkboxes in Phalcon

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, phalcon

I'm building a form which reads a list of keywords from a database.
The model is simple: each user have different keywords associated in the database, so I don't know the number of them.

In the form I want to render all the user's associated keywords with a checkbox list, so the user can decide which keyword save in a special group.
Of course I want to render the name of the keyword but I want to obtain the "id" of it.

I don't find any documentation of this. I just found the typical:

```
$keywords = new Check('keywords', array(
        'value' => '1'
    ));
$keywords->setLabel('Keywords');
$this->add($keywords);
```

to put in the form, but it is useless. In the view I wrote

```
<div class="control-group">
        {{ form.label('keywords', ['class': 'control-label']) }}
        <div class="controls">
            {{ form.render('keywords', ['class': 'form-control']) }}
        </div>
</div>
```

And I see a checkbox (with value 1). I imagine the solution should be something like the SELECT (which I use in another form). Something like:

```
$idkeyword = new Select('keyword',
        Keyword::find($string), [
        "useEmpty"  =>  true,
        "emptyText" =>  "Por favor selecciona...", 
        "using" => ["idkeyword", "trackeable"],
        ]);
$idkeyword->setLabel('Keyword');
$idkeyword->addValidators(array(
        new PresenceOf(array(
            'message' => 'idkeyword requerida'
            ))
        ));
$this->add($idkeyword);
```

In the view I would like to have something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="1" />Keyword 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="2" />Keyword 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="3" />Keyword 3<br />
```

When "Keyword X" is in the database and "X" is its id.

I would be glad to hear any help. I hope my question is well formulated. If not, I will accept all comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `Phalcon\Forms\Element\Check` is meant for a single checkbox, so if you want to use it for multiple checkboxes, you will have to write a loop:

```
// You should get these options from the database
$options = [1 => 'Keyword 1', 2 => 'Keyword 2', 3 => 'Keyword 3'];

foreach($options as $key => $value)
{
    // Create a checkbox for each option
    $keywords = new Check('keywords'.$key, [
        'name'  => 'chk_group',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'value' => $value
    ]);

    // Create a label for each option so the user can click on this
    $keywords->setLabel($value);

    $this->add($keywords);
}
```

then in the view:

```
{% for element in form %}
    {{ element.label(['class': 'control-label']) }}
    {{ element.render() }}
{% endfor %}
```